Compare records within the same table and find missing setup
I'm trying to write an SQL in Oracle where I compare only two items in the same table and find the records where item2 is missing the warehouse setup where the warehouses exist in comparison to setup of Item1.
Please accept my thanks for your assistance towards adapting the SQL for which I almost have the answer but then I have to do manual adjustments to get the records looking good.
This is what my table looks like:
Warehouse Item
Alabama Item1
Arizona Item1
California  Item1
Colorado    Item1
Georgia Item1
Illinois    Item1
Maine   Item1
Montana Item1
Texas   Item1
Alabama Item2
Arizona Item2
Colorado    Item2
Illinois    Item2
Texas   Item2
and I'm trying to locate records like:
Warehouse   Item
California  Item2
Georgia Item2
Maine   Item2
Montana Item2
The SQL I wrote is:
SELECT
  t1.Item, t1.Warehouse
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.Item = 'Item1'
and NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM table t2
                   WHERE t2.Item1 <> t1.Item2
                     AND t2.Warehouse = t1.Warehouse
                     and t2.Item = ('Item2'));

Thank you again in advance.

Please do not post data example as images, use text instead. It is time consuming creating a testing environment from images.

Ok, i will edit it now. thanks

Not done this before, so please bear with me.

Note that tables have rows, not records.

This is pretty trivial problem. It can be solved by different ways. For example using LEFT JOIN:
SELECT Items.Warehouse, 'Item2'
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Items ItemsCopy ON 
    Items.Warehouse = ItemsCopy.Warehouse AND
    ItemsCopy.Item = 'Item2' 
WHERE Items.Item = 'Item1' AND ItemsCopy.Warehouse IS NULL;

or WHERE NOT EXISTS condition:
SELECT Items.Warehouse, 'Item2'
FROM Items
WHERE Items.Item = 'Item1' AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ItemsCopy.Warehouse 
    FROM Items ItemsCopy WHERE
        Items.Warehouse = ItemsCopy.Warehouse AND
        ItemsCopy.Item = 'Item2' 
);

Test the solutions on fiddle

Thanks Slava. But this did not work. Maybe because there is no reference to 'Item1' in your SQL.

I just edited my solution. Try it now

Thanks Slava, yes this worked perfectly. thanks for your assistance. Appreciate it really. thank you.
